# why bootstrap doesn't work with js vanilla?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

why when i use bootstrap with vanilla JavaScript my slideshow gets crashed it seems like there is a time out or something ..

i don't know whythis is happening by the way when i remove bootstrap he is working without any problem here is my code:

i tried to remove bootstrap and the slider works without any problem but i wanna use bootstrap is there any solution here is my code

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="logo-box">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- <nav class="main-nav">
        <div class="col-sm">
      <ul class="main-nav__items">
        <li class="main-nav__item">
          <a href="#">services</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <li class="main-nav__item">
          <a href="#">reservation</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <li  class="main-nav__item">
          <a href="#">menu</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <li  class="main-nav__item">
          <a href="#">our chefs</a>
        </li>
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
        <li  class="main-nav__item">
          <a href="#">events</a>
        </li>
      </div>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div> -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">reservation</a>
        </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">menu</a>
        </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">our chefs</a>
        </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">events</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <!-- <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div> -->
    <img src="images/food3.png" class="img">
    <!-- <div class="text">Caption Text</div> -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <!-- <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div> -->
    <img src="images/pizza.png" class="img" >
    <!-- <div class="text">Caption Two</div> -->
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <!-- <div class="numbertext">3/3</div> -->
    <img src="images/hamburger2.png" class="img" >
    <!-- <div class="text">Caption Three</div> -->
  </div>


<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div class="dotz">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {box-sizing:border-box;
margin:0;}
.img{
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}
.slideshow-container{
  max-width: 93rem;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
 .dot {
   position: relative;
   top: -30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active{
  background-color: #ff9900;
}
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #ff9900;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
.dotz{
  text-align:center;
}
@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

**javascript**

```
var slideIndex=1;
 showSlides(slideIndex);
 function currentSlide(n){
   showSlides(slideIndex=n);
 }
 function showSlides(n){
   var i;
   var slides=document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
   var dots=document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
   for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display="none";
   }
   for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
     dots[i].className=dots[i].className.replace(" active","");
   }
   slides[slideIndex-1].style.display="block";
   dots[slideIndex-1].className+=" active";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming the **fade** class to something else (for example: **js-fade**). Bootstrap uses fade class for some other elements (eg. modal) so that might be causing your issue.